# CefSharp.wpf web browser navigated event (C# .Net)

Tags: c#, wpf, oauth-2.0, webbrowser-control, cefsharp

Is it possible to hook up an event like Navigated with the Webbrowser control (built-in)? I need to perform oAuth in a desktop application and there i need to know if the authentication code has been added to the redirect_uri.

I was using WebBrowser control that is built in and has the events like Navigating and Navigated but i was facing an issue regarding ieframe.dll/navcancl.htm so i decided to go with CefSharp.wpf ChromiumWebBrowser but I'm not being able to locate any events that can be called when the browser has finished navigating to the URL.

This is what i have done in the xaml

```
 <wpf:ChromiumWebBrowser Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
        x:Name="ChromiumBrowser"
        WebBrowser="{Binding WebBrowser, Mode=OneWayToSource}" FrameLoadStart="ChromiumBrowser_OnFrameLoadStart"
        Title="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

and when the user requests to authenticate, I'm setting the address like

```
ChromiumBrowser.Address = NavigateUrl
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ChromiumWebBrowser` has a `LoadingStateChanged` event with `LoadingStateChangedArgs`, which has an `IsLoading` property. It also has a `FrameLoadEnd` event, which is raised when a frame in the page finishes loading.

Comment: In the current release the event is called `NavStateChanged`, in the upcoming `43` release it has been renamed to `LoadingStateChanged` to keep things inline with the `upstream` `CEF` project. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/41/CefSharp/IWebBrowser.cs#L48

Comment: For reference the current stable release is `41.0.1`

Comment: I installed it from Nuget and its v43 (prerelease) so i can see the changes already @amaitland :)